# Getting started with SQL iOS

Tags: mysql, ios, sql, objective-c, sqlite

I have a database of common first and last names and I am not sure if it is SQLite or something else.

What I need to do is have a method that checks if a string is found in the database, to confirm if it is a common name or not.

The beginning of my data looks like this:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 2.11.9.4
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: May 12, 2009 at 10:43 AM
-- Server version: 5.0.67
-- PHP Version: 5.2.6

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `socialne_names`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `first`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `first` (
  `firstname` text NOT NULL,
  FULLTEXT KEY `firstname` (`firstname`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `first`
--

INSERT INTO `first` (`firstname`) VALUES
('firstname'),
('Aaron'),
('Aaron'),
('Abbey'),
('Abbie'),
```

Can anyone advise me on how I can do this?

Comment: How does this relate to iOS ?

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a SQL dump from a MySQL database, generated by phpMyAdmin.  You won't be able to import that directly into SQLite, which I assume is what you want to do on the iOS device.

It will need to be massaged to import it into SQLite, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE first (firstname TEXT);
INSERT INTO first (firstname) VALUES ("Aaron");
INSERT INTO first (firstname) VALUES ("Abby");
```

From there, you would package the generated SQLite database in the application bundle. At first launch, copy the file to a writeable location.  You can either use raw SQLite or an ObjC abstraction layer like [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) to query your SQLite database.